# Every root command fails with "command not found" through ssh, but works in VNC console?

Tags: ssh, debian

I have a VPS which I access via SSH. After I updated to Debian 10, I cannot run root commands any more when logged in as root via ssh (I already rebooted). When using my hosts' VNC connection console for access, everything works as usual.

As an example take `iptables` but this is valid for all commands.

```
marius:/home/afh whoami                                                                         
root                 
marius:/home/afh iptables                                                                       
zsh: command not found: iptables
marius:/home/afh apt-get install iptables                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
iptables is already the newest version (1.8.2-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have tried re-installing as suggested [on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504351/the-program-iptables-is-currently-not-installed):

```
marius:/home/afh apt-get --reinstall install iptables                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 399 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 iptables amd64 1.8.2-4 [399 kB]
Fetched 399 kB in 0s (1,162 kB/s)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 1.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
(Reading database ... 327810 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iptables_1.8.2-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking iptables (1.8.2-4) over (1.8.2-4) ...
Setting up iptables (1.8.2-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 0 KiB

Total disk space freed by localepurge: 0 KiB

marius:/home/afh iptables -L                                                                    
zsh: command not found: iptables
marius:/home/afh whoami                                                                         
root
```

PATH looks fine, it could be the problem according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186808/every-command-fails-with-command-not-found-after-changing-bash-profile) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493287/command-not-found-when-using-ssh-and-non-absolute-commands):

```
marius:/home/afh echo $PATH                                                                      
/root/.bin:/home/afh/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

bash also fails:

```
root@marius:/home/afh# iptables -L
bash: iptables: command not found
```

Comment: `PATH` may not look fine, there is no `sbin`. As a temporary workaround `sudo` should give you a basic administrative `PATH`. Can you invoke `sudo iptables --help`? Compare the "normal" `PATH` with `sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'`. If my hypothesis is right then you (we) should investigate why the `PATH` is what it is.

Comment: BTW nrever permit remote `root` logins! Use either `su` or `sudo` after having logged in as a regular user.

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell us how you become `root`.

If you're using plain `su` then upgrading to Buster broke it—actually it fixed it since it was broken ;-)

The idea is that plain `su` now does not use the `PATH` variable from the *target* user's environment (`root` in your case), and the `PATH` of a regular user does not contain the `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` directories, and that's why `/usr/sbin/iptables` is not accessible using its unadorned (short) name.

The quick fix is to use `su -` which forces this program to switch into "login" mode.

See [this](https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster) for more.